GeoPackage draws in the wrong location using ThinkGeo
I have a GeoPackage(.gpkg) file that I'm adding to my ThinkGeo WPF map.  I'm adding the file using the code below:
        var layerOverlay = new LayerOverlay();

        var gdalFeatureLayer = new GdalFeatureLayer(@"./MyData/mora_surficial_geology.gpkg");
        gdalFeatureLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.DefaultPointStyle = PointStyle.CreateSimplePointStyle(PointSymbolType.Circle,GeoColors.LightBlue,4);
        gdalFeatureLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.DefaultLineStyle = LineStyle.CreateSimpleLineStyle(GeoColor.FromArgb(128,GeoColors.LightSteelBlue), 2F, GeoColors.Brown, 2F, false);
        gdalFeatureLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.DefaultAreaStyle = AreaStyle.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.FromArgb(64,GeoColors.LightGreen), GeoColors.Black, 1);
        gdalFeatureLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.ApplyUntilZoomLevel = ApplyUntilZoomLevel.Level20;
        layerOverlay.Layers.Add(gdalFeatureLayer);

        MapView.Overlays.Add(layerOverlay);

When the map renders, my dataset is showing up in the Mediterranean ocean instead of in Washington State:

What can I do to get my GeoPackage data to show up in the correct location in Washington?

When your features show up in the incorrect location, it's typically a projection issue.  I did a search for mora_surficial_geology.gpkg and found that it is in EPSG:26910 (NAD83 / UTM Zone 10N).   To reproject this data into your basemap's projection - EPSG:3857(Spherical Mercator), you can use a ProjectionConverter object:
        var projectionConverter = new ProjectionConverter(26910, 3857);
        gdalFeatureLayer.FeatureSource.ProjectionConverter = projectionConverter;

The result places your GeoPackage data in Washington State in Mount Rainier National Park.
Your issue is a very common one, so I put together a quick post and sample you can read about here.
